# Segmentation fault mid-way through traversing linked list in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm relatively new to C and am working on a program that creates a linked list of address information, sorted by city alphabetically. When I attempt to print the list out (just name and city), I get a segmentation fault with one specific entry every time, about 3/4 of the way through the list. I read the data line by line from a file using fgets, but a problem that I had is that the "City State Zip" are all on one line in that format, but I only want to print the city. This code traverses through an already made linked list of entries and tries to print out the name and city of each entry, in order. I can move through and print names, but the one of the entries is giving the segfault when I try to do cities as well. Since some cities are two words, I had to put code in that accounted for that (that's why I have those four words - there's probably a better way, but that's what I thought to do)

```
void printList() {
    struct addressEntry *current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        char *end;

        end = current->firstName + strlen(current->firstName) - 1;
        while (end > current->firstName && isspace(*end)) end--;
        *(end + 1) = 0;

        end = current->lastName + strlen(current->lastName) - 1;
        while (end > current->lastName && isspace(*end)) end--;
        *(end + 1) = 0;

        char * myCity = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

        char* firstWord = strtok(current->city," ");
        char* secondWord = strtok(NULL, " ");
        char* thirdWord = strtok(NULL, " ");
        char* fourthWord = strtok(NULL, " ");

        printf("Created four words from white spaces: %s_%s_%s_%s_\n", firstWord, secondWord, thirdWord, fourthWord);

        myCity = (char *) realloc(myCity, 2 + strlen(firstWord) + strlen(secondWord));

        if (strlen(fourthWord) != 5) {
            printf("Made it to one-word city\n");
            myCity = firstWord;
        }
        else {
            printf("Made it to two-word city\n");
            strcpy(myCity, firstWord);
            strcat(myCity, " ");
            strcat(myCity, secondWord);
            printf("Finished two word city: %s\n",myCity);
        }

        current = current->nextEntry;
    }
}
```

The segmentation fault occurs after the `realloc()` function is called. When the `printf()` call printing each of the four words is executed for the particular entry that causes the segfault, it looks like this:

```
Tampa_NC_28211
_(null)_
```

I don't understand pointers crazy well, so I've been very confused why it's just this entry that won't work and what I could do to get around it. I've tried adding a little if statement after `realloc()` that checks if `fourthWord` is `NULL`, but it never entered it. Any help on how to avoid the segfault?

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger? That is step #1.

Comment: `myCity = realloc(...); ... myCity = ...` is a bug. You're leaking memory.

Comment: I'm using the terminal on a mac and it won't recognize gdb command. I don't know of another debugger but I was able to narrow down where the fault was with a bunch of printf statements. 

is there a quick fix about the memory issue? Sorry, I'm used to java so I'm not very experienced with having control of memory allocation

Comment: Instead of parsing forward, why not parse backward? Extract zip and state. Whatever is left is the City. This will work even if City name varies from 1 or more words.

Answer (score 0):

The `strtok()` function returns `NULL` when its first argument is `NULL` and there are no more tokens in the input string.  You do not test for that; if it occurs, you simply record the `NULL` in one of your variables.  Thus, if you encounter a city line containing fewer than four tokens, you will end up passing at least one `NULL` among the `printf()` arguments.  That would produce undefined behavior, and a failure such as you observe would be a likely actual result.

More generally, you should always check function return values for error conditions if you in fact care whether an error occurred, and you usually should care whether an error occurred.  In the code presented, for example, you should check the return values of `malloc()` and `realloc()`, in addition to that of `strtok()`.  You could also check the return values of your `printf()`s, but in this case maybe you don't care so much about those.

Also, as @melpomene first observed, you allocate (and then reallocate) memory, but never free it.  When variable `myCity` goes out of scope at the end of each iteration of your loop, or earlier when you assign a new value to it, you lose the only pointer to that allocated memory.  That constitutes a memory leak.  Leaking memory does not ordinarily cause a segmentation fault, however.